# $_server['PHP_SELF'] Getting Error while retriving data after clicking submit from recordset

Tags: php

**From below code i am displaying values from tables. The Problem is when i am clicking button no value is displayed. I want the recordset value as echo using PHP_SELF.*
****Here echo "". $row['First_name'] i am trying to fetc recordset via form to display variable without use of javascript or any function****

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test.billing";
        try
        {
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
            $count = mysql_affected_rows();
            if($count>0)
            {
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $i++;
        ?>
        <div class="CSS_Table_Example" style="width:800px;height:100px;">
          <table border="1" width="800" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
             <td width="5%" nowrap>ID</td>
             <th width="15%" align="right" nowrap> First Name</th>
              <th width="15%" align="right" nowrap> Last Name</th>
              <th width="15%" align="right" nowrap> Password</th>
              <th width="25%" align="right" nowrap> E-mail</th>
              <th width="25%" align="right" nowrap> Edit</th>
             </tr> 
             <tr>
               <td width="5%" nowrap><?php echo $i; ?></td>
               <td width="15%" nowrap><?php echo "". $row['First_name']; ?> </td>
               <td width="15%" nowrap><?php echo "". $row['Last_name']; ?>  </td>
               <td width="15%" nowrap><?php echo "". $row['Password']; ?>   </td>
               <td width="25%" nowrap><?php echo "". $row['Email']; ?>  </td>
          <td width="25%" align="right" nowrap>
              <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
              <input type="SUBMIT" name="Submit" size="30"></form>  </td>
           </tr> 
          </table>
        </div>
        <?Php
            }
            if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
            {
             echo "". $row['First_name'];

            }
            }
    else
    {
      Error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);  
    }
```

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃:   That is probably a typo. If you look at the code in the question, you can see that he's using `$_SERVER`.

Comment: I think `rror_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` should be `error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` in else block above `catch`

Comment: First off affected rows cannot be used with select statements, instead the function num_rows() can be used to count the amount of rows returned http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not `rror_reporting()` it should be `error_reporting()`.
2. `try/catch` is redundant, you have nothing that throws exceptions in that code.

And that's what I got from just a quick glance. Please consider rereading the relevant parts of the PHP manual, and learn how to write proper code. I also suggest you grab yourself a good IDE/editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: please review the code error againg,due to unformated content the other part is not showing error.